# How to go to next Activity on clicking the textview kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I've used TextView and made it clickable in Kotlin. This is a voice recognition app and as soon as I click the textview I want it to enter another activity.

```
class STTFragment : Fragment() {
lateinit var recognizer: SpeechRecognizer
lateinit var chatPresenter: IChatPresenter
private val thisActivity = activity

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    chatPresenter = ChatPresenter(requireContext())
}

@NonNull
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sttframe, container, false)
    if (thisActivity is ChatActivity)
        thisActivity.fabsetting.hide()
    promptSpeechInput()
    setupCommands(rootView)
    return rootView
}

private fun setupCommands(rootView: View) {
    var voiceCommand = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.voiceCommands)
    var voiceCommandsList = voiceCommand.toCollection(ArrayList())
    rootView.clickableCommands.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
    rootView.clickableCommands.adapter = VoiceCommandsAdapter(voiceCommandsList, activity)


}
```

That is the **sttFragment** class

```
class VoiceCommandsAdapter(val items: ArrayList<String>, val context: Context?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<VoiceCommandsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    lateinit var chatPresenter: IChatPresenter

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
        chatPresenter = ChatPresenter(context as Context)
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_voice_commands, parent, false))

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder?.voiceCommand?.text = items.get(position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val voiceCommand: TextView = view.voiceCommand

        init {
            view.setOnClickListener {
                val chatMessage = items[adapterPosition]
                val splits = chatMessage.split("\n".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }
                val message = splits.joinToString(" ")
                if (!chatMessage.isEmpty()) {
                    chatPresenter.sendMessage(message, items[adapterPosition])

                }


            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is the **voicecommandAdapter** class.
How can I modify the code such that as soon as I click the command it should go to another activity.

It should not wait until the recognizer timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to be as brief and clear as I can. The right way to do this would be:

1. **Implement View.OnClickListener to your Fragment**
   You will need to implement the onClick method in your Fragment too. Inside it, is where you are gonna trigger the navigation to the another activity.
2. **Add one more argument to your Adapter constructor:**
   `VoiceCommandsAdapter(val items: ArrayList<String>, val context: Context?, val clickListener: View.OnClickListener)`
3. **Override `onClick()` function in your adapter**
4. In your `onBindViewHolder` add the click listener to your TextView

   `holder?.voiceCommand?.text.setOnClickListener {clickListener.onClick()}`

*Note before next and final step: What you are doing is simply passing a click callback to your adapter, so that when you click in your TextView it goes back to your fragment `onClick(View)` function.

This is a good practice because you want to do your next step in your fragment, this is, the navigation part. 

The alternative here would be to pass an instance of your activity to your adapter and treat the navigation logic in there, but that's bad practice (to pass activity/fragment instances around)*

5. **Navigate to new activity in `onClick(View)` in your `STTFragment`**
   Inside your `onClick(View)` function, is where you will trigger the navigation logic. To do this just add:
   `val intent = Intent(activity, TargetActivity.class)`
   `activity.startActivity(intent)`

Comment: kotlin doesnt accept view.OnClickListener in sttfragment

Comment: Shen you declare your constructor you need to implement the onClickListener. You will need to implement the onClick method: if in windows or linux do alt + insert and then select implement methods. There you will find the onClick method. Just select it and press ok.

Comment: rootView.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(activity,ChatActivity::class.java)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            startActivity(intent)

Comment: I have created this but it's not going back as soon as clicked.

Comment: Where are you pressing back, on the device or at the back button (top left corner)?